# AngularJS: linking a bootstrap collapse div to fields in app.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am an Angularjs beginner and I am trying to make a data driven accordion. I do not wish to use angular-ui. I followed the tutorial for collapse Bootstrap 3 and I came up with this code, but I am stuck with trying to make it data driven.

HTML:

```
 <div class="my-page__my-list-acc" ng-
    if="field.fieldAccordions">
          <div id="accordion_{{ $index }}">
  <div class="panel my-panel-overrides">
    <a class="my-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{{ $index }}" data-target="#collapse1">
       {{field.fieldAccordionHeader }} </a>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse in">
      {{ field.fieldAccordionItem }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
fieldAccordions:  [{
          fieldAccordionHeader: 'text',
                    fieldAccordionItem: 'text',
                    }],
                  },{

fieldAccordions:  [{
          fieldAccordionHeader: 'text',

                    fieldAccordionItem: 'text',          
                    }],
                  },{
```

I am having trouble linking the different parts of the accordion with the html. The program finds fieldAccordions and creates the panel, but it does not get to the fieldAccordionHeader and fieldAccordionItem sections.

Also, the second issue I am having is that if I create different fieldAccordions items, clicking on every one would simply close/open the original fieldAccordions field.

Some help would be appreciated. I am aware that this is probably straight forward, but it would help me understand it better. A plunkr would be ideal!

Comment: Your JS doesn't make any sense.  It is a poorly/partially formed array of objects duplicated.  Please clean up your own question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you are trying to render accordions from an array of objects each representing an individual accordion.  If that's the case, I would place the accordion inside and ng-repeat, like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('accordions', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.fieldAccordions = [{
   fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 1',
   fieldAccordionItems: [{
     desc: 'Item 1 - A'
   }, {
     desc: 'Item 1 - B'
   }]
 }, {
   fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 2',
   fieldAccordionItems: [{
     desc: 'Item 2'
   }]
 }, {
   fieldAccordionHeader: 'Header 3',
   fieldAccordionItems: [{
     desc: 'Item 3'
   }]
 }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="accordions">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Accordions</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="field in fieldAccordions track by $index">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{ $index }}">
            {{ field.fieldAccordionHeader }} </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
           <div ng-repeat="item in field.fieldAccordionItems track by $index">{{ item.desc }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note:  I've used the standard Bootstrap 3 classes since you didn't provide your custom styles in the question.

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thank you for your help. One more question: How can I list multiple items in each header ? Right now it only works with one

Comment: @ClaudiuRemy - I don't understand what you mean.  Please update the fieldAccordions array in your to accurately reflect your actual scenario and then I will be able to answer you.

Comment: adding fieldAccordionItem2 after fieldAccordionItem1 will not create a new field under fieldAccordionHeader

Comment: @ClaudiuRemy -  I updated my answer to reflect multiple items per accordion.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have really gained some knowledge thanks to you